# slicer apprixmation for 3d print

Tags: 3d-printing

I have a problem when I design models for 3d printing: I always add features that are too small for my printer settings.  Is there a way for me to visualize the resolution of my printer.  I imagine splitting the scene into voxels of size .1 mm cubed, and then viewing only the voxels with intersect with any of the objects in the scene.   Is there anything out there that is even close to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be 100% accurate but the **Remesh modifier** could give you a idea of what the 3D printed object would look like.

[image]

To get the voxeled style, choose **Blocks** from the Mode menu.

To get the right size I would add a voxel-sized cube (whose dimension can easily controlled in the Properties panel) as reference, then tweak the modifier's parameters (start from the the **Octree depth** and than refine with the **Scale**) till the subdivision are about the same size of the reference cube.

[image]

**Warning**: if you alter the object's bounding box size, you must re-eyeball the subdivision rate.